# How to get apps names and its live versions using fastlane

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I need to make a report with apps names and it's live versions. 
my apple id is assigned as an admin in multiple teams and I need to loop over all apps inside every appstore team and get its name and live version.

I could get apps names and versions only for one development team using following script now I need to get it for all development teams that my apple id is assigned to.

```
lane :get_apps_names_and_versions do |options|
  require "spaceship" 
  all_apps = ""
  Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all.collect do |app|
  all_apps << "#{app.name} #{app.live_version.version} \n"
  end
  File.write('all_apps', all_apps[0..-3])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I just did it by get all teams and loop over them then get apps for each team.**

```
lane :get_apps_names_and_versions do |options|
  require "spaceship" 
  clientTunes = Spaceship::Tunes.login(options[:appleID],options[:password])
  all_apps = ""
    clientTunes.teams.each do |team|
      ENV['FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_ID'] = "#{team['contentProvider']['contentProviderId']}"
      Spaceship::Tunes.select_team
      Spaceship::Tunes::Application.all.collect do |app| 
        begin
          live_version = app.live_version.version 
          all_apps << "#{app.name} #{live_version} #{app.bundle_id}\n"
          UI.message "#{app.name} #{live_version} #{app.bundle_id}\n"
          rescue
            all_apps << "#{app.name} NO Live Version \n"
            UI.message "#{app.name} NO Live Version \n"
          end
        end
      end 
  File.write('all_apps', all_apps[0..-3])
  end
```

Comment: My friend, you are amazing. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyF I'm very happy that I could help you :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're like me and wanted to obtain the live version without having to use the Spacehip login (e.g. in a CI/CD pipeline), and use the API key, you can do it like this:

```
app_store_build_number
live_version = lane_context[SharedValues::LATEST_VERSION]
```

Check the "Lane Variables" section: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/app_store_build_number/